# Error: The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type

Tags: entity-framework, generics, reflection

```
public partial class GridMastercontrol<TEntity> : UserControl
{
private System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TEntity> _osMain; // error here
}
```

I am unable to declare an object set of generic type.
Please help me how to do that.

The error message is-
The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add generic constraint to your class declaration:

```
public partial class GridMastercontrol<TEntity> : UserControl where TEntity : class
```

You have to do that, because `ObjectSet<TEntity>` already has one:

```
public class ObjectSet<TEntity> : ObjectQuery<TEntity>, 
        IObjectSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, 
        IQueryable, IEnumerable
where TEntity : class
```

Comment: Although, I have resolved my problem yesterday, by myself. But, thanks for the solution. It works...